# Usage of Who vs that

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

> 1. I know the man **that** came here.
> 2. I know the man **who** came here.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in this case.

**Who** is used when referring to people.

**That** is used to refer to people, animals, groups, or things, but who is generally preferred when referring to people.

Source: [click](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/who-vs-which-vs-that/who-vs-that/)

**EDIT** I also found a similar question on English SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-vs-that